# Issue on removing jar from deployment assembly in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, liferay, ivy

hi guy iam facing a problem in my Liferay Eclipse project. I have included in it some required jar files using **Right_click_on_project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly**.
when i try to remove them using the same procedure an clicking on **Apply** button they are removed. but when i come back again the deleted jar figure again. doing and doing again the result is always the same: the jar are not removed!

how to delete those jar as they are not needed anymore in my project? i tryed to manually delete them. but their entries always figure in the **Deployment Assembly** with yellow mark.

Ian using eclipse Luna with liferay plugin 6.1 and Ivy.

Comment: You say you're using ivy? If that is the case your jar dependencies would be listed in the "ivy.xml" file.

Comment: A mistake iam using Ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured how to get rid of those jar file.

i went to the directory liferay_sdk -> portlet -> eclipse_plugin_project_name -> .settings

and then i deleted entries relative to those included jar file in file **org.eclipse.wst.common.componen**t.